# Why bootstrap style is not getting applied in jsFiddle?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/KNM4q/97/

Can you please point out the reason of why Bootstrap 's default style of `<ol>` is not getting set in this code?

Pasting a part of HTML from fiddle.

```
<ul>                                 
    <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in val.items"><span class="indent ng-scope ng-binding">Tables
        &amp; Chairs</span></li>
    <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in val.items"><span class="indent ng-scope ng-binding">Sofas</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's overwritten by `normalize.css` used in jsfiddle:

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Just uncheck Normalized CSS option on the left ("Choose Framework" section).

http://jsfiddle.net/KNM4q/100/